# Mathematical view of z-fighting

Tags: opengl, math, zbuffer

to understand how z-fighting is working i got this question.

Consider the point `p = (0, 0, −500)` given in the local coordinate system of
the camera. Derive the depth values assigned to p in the different stages of
the pipeline described above, i.e., derive the depth value of p in eye space, in
normalized device coordinates `([−1, 1])`, in the range [0, 1] and the final depth
buffer value.With n = 200 and f = 1000 and m = 24

I think the secound step for this procedure is: `z1=z * -(f+n)/(f-n) - 2fn/(f-n)`
from the prospective transformation matrix.
After that `z2= (1/2)*z1 + 1/2`

But i dont know how the transformation should look like in the eye space and what the last step is.

i hope someone can help me :) `

Comment: The last step is the homogenous divide, i.e. v' = v/v.w – however to understand Z fighting this is irrelevant. Z-fighting is caused by numerical roundoff errors in the interpolation of nearly identical boundary values (vertex positions) resulting in a variation of some ordering operator (<, > and such).

Answer (score 0):

To get from *object space* ("local coordinate system")  you have to take the model (object-to-world) and view (world-to-eye) transformations into account. Usually, these are affine transforms described by some matrices. The model and view transform might be composed to a modelView matrix, since the world space is not explicitely needed. And that is the way the old GL fixed-function pipeline worked.

Since it is not clear what exactly is given, I'll just assume we know the matrices or you can determine/compute them from whatever is given.  Since you only need `z_eye`, you can just use the dot product of the third row of these matrices with your input vector `p` (as you already did in case of the projection).

After the projection, you got `clip space` and need to do the homogenous divide by `w_clip` - That means that calculating only `z` is not enough. You need the `w` coordinate also, as defined by applying the projection matrix. In the typical case, `w_clip=-z_eye`. But in the general case, you might get something else. That means that you might need `x_eye`, `y_eye` and `w_eye` also, since the model and view transforms might be not affine (very unlikely), play around with `w` (a crude way for scaling) or the projection direction is not identical to the `z` axis (still not very likely, but in theory perfectly possible).

After `z_ndc=z_clip/w_clip`, you need the viewport transform. OpenGL will transform the range `[-1,1]` to `[0,1]` here by default, and your question assumes the same. Finally, the value is converted to the final format. Since by default, a integer depth buffer is used, the range `[0,1]` is just linearily mapped to `[0,max]`, and the fractional part ignored. 
Your queuestion seems to suggest that a 24-bit depth buffer is used, so `max=2^24-1`.